# Remove old file checkouts from CVS repository

Tags: version-control, cvs

While checking out some files from our CVS repository the other day I noticed that someone else that no longer works here already had the file checked out. It seems that he didn't undo his checkouts before he left so they are now left stuck in the repository. His user accounts and files have already been removed so there's no way I could just log onto his machine and undo the checkouts.

Is there a way to remove these checkouts on the server?

Thanks

Comment: I always thought that CVS is Copy-Modify-Merge-style-based and thus does not have a concept of a "check out" on the server.

Comment: It does have check out on the server. Doing the checkouts is not a required thing but when there are multiple people working on a project it is useful to know who else is modifying the same files that you are.

Comment: Check your terminology. A "Checkout" in CVS is always non-exclusive. What you're talking about is probably what is usually referrred to as "Lock" in CVS-lingo, i.e. `cvs admin -l` (marked deprecated in most versions of CVS(NT)). Or are you talking about CVSNT's "Reserved Edit"?

Comment: ...or put differently: Please clarify by what workflow exactly the file was "locked" and then we can tell you how to undo it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the answer to that question is. We are using a 3rd party CVS plugin for Visual Studio that deals with the CVS repository and the lingo it uses is "Checkout." I am thinking that what it is doing is the reserved edit. I think I may have solved the problem but it involves manually removing editor and watcher tags from the fileattr.xml files on the repository machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your mention of `fileattr.xml` in your comments it sounds like you're using CVSNT. In that case, removing those files from the repository is indeed a feasible, but rather brute-force approach. If your VS-plugin does indeed use CVSNT's reserved edit command to implement the exclusive checkouts then the following command should have removed the edit locks as well:

```
cvs unedit -u <username> <files...>
```

(where `<username>` is the name of the user currently holding the "lock")

This requires that your user account is regarded as an admin by the CVS server, though. There are various ways to do this, the simplest being listing your user name in the `CVSROOT/admin` file. If I remember correctly, CVSNT also supports repo admins via a special windows user group. You'd have to check the documentation for specifics.

Comment: @ted214: Thanks for accepting my answer! Feel free to vote, too. ;)

Comment: I am 7 short of the required 15 reputation required to vote so sorry, I can't vote it up.

Comment: @ted214: No worries. I wasn't aware of that limit (anymore). Feel free to find something to answer to remedy that. ;) Anyway, so `unedit -u` did indeed do the trick then, yes?

Comment: Yes, after I added myself to the admin file `unedit -u` did the trick. It seems like somewhat of a security issue with CVS that I found even after the former employee's Windows user account was deleted I could still use his information to authenticate to the server (because his name was still in the passwd file). I'm glad I found that out as well while trying to fix this issue.

Comment: @ted214: Sounds like you're using the `:pserver:`-protocol, which is indeed completely independent from Windows user accounts. This protocol is inherently insecure (IIRC it even transmits the password in plain-text) and typically only used for anonymous read-only access. If you want security and integration with Windows user accounts you should use the `:sspi:` protocol instead. Hope this helps.